# Cannot resolve symbol com.google.firebase.messaging.Message

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm following the below link to implement Firebase Messaging to send messages to multiple devices

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/send-multiple#build_send_requests

I'm almost done with the implementation but just stuck at the last stage (Build send requests)

In the below code

```
Message message = Message.builder()
    .putData("score", "850")
    .putData("time", "2:45")
    .setTopic(topic)
    .build();
```

I'm getting the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'Message'`

Also in the line

```
String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
```

When I Ctrl+click the send() method, the argument `message` is being shown as instance of `RemoteMessage` and not `Message` with return type of `void` and not `String`

Am I missing any dependencies or is there any change in implementation in the latest library of firebase messaging?

I'm using the following (latest) Firebase version in my app level `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
```

Comment: Kindly Check if you have imported proper Message Import, which Belongs to Firebase Messaging. Else paste your imports.

Comment: The Message class requires import com.google.firebase.messaging.Message but I'm not able to import this as I cannot find it (though I'm able to find com ggogle.firebase.messaging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Message` class is inside the Firebase admin sdk but you cannot use that in your android project, you can only use firebase admin sdk in the server side and then you will be able to use the `Message` class. Check the docs for reference:-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics

To be able to use the admin sdk, you need a server like `Tomcat`, you should also use java version 8, then you can follow the following tutorial:-

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#prerequisites

---

**Original Answer**

<strike>You need to use `RemoteMessage` class, example:</strike>

```
RemoteMessage message = RemoteMessage.builder()
    .addData("score", "850")
    .addData("time", "2:45")
    .build();
```

Check here for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.Builder.html

Comment: I tried it but I want to send message to users subscribed to a particular Topic, and this method has no arguments for topic

Comment: The `Message` class is inside the Firebase admin sdk but you cannot use that in your android project, you can only use firebase admin sdk in the server side and then you will be able to use the `Message` class https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/manage-topics

Comment: Ohhh... Thanks Peter! Now I got it. Actually I'm new to FCM and not sure where do I put this code on my server and how do I call it from Android. Can you please guide me on this.

Comment: U need a server like tomcat that will have java 8 and then u can follow this https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#prerequisites

Comment: Okay... Thanks for the help... Just worried about 1 thing. I want to achieve functionality of sending notifications from one user to multiple users from my android app. So am I on the right track?

Comment: yes let all the users subscribe to the topic then in the backend set the topic and using `send()` everyone subscribed to that topic will recieve the notification.