# send (com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage) in FirebaseMessaging cannot be applied to (android.os.Message)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm working on push notification here i pushed notification from firebase console it works 
now i want to push notification through coding so i tried

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

public class LockScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button btn;
    EditText t1;
    TextView status;
    Password_Database password_database;
    String v1, v2;
    Context cn;
    String str = "";

    public LockScreen() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_screen);
        cn = this;
        password_database = new Password_Database(cn);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.unlock_btn);
        t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.unlock_pass);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.App_name);

        // v1 and v2 get data from background services
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            v1 = extras.getString("name");
            v2 = extras.getString("pack");

            //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
        }


        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (v1.equals(t1.getText().toString())) {

                    Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(v2);
                    launchIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(launchIntent);

                    sendToTopic();


                    finish();

                    Toast.makeText(LockScreen.this, "Password Correct", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LockScreen.this, "wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    t1.setText("");
                }

            }

        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        v2 = "";
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
        LockScreen.this.finish();

    }

    public void sendToTopic() {
        // [START send_to_topic]
        // The topic name can be optionally prefixed with "/topics/".
        String topic = "notification";

        // See documentation on defining a message payload.
        Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("score", "850")
                .putData("time", "2:45")
                .setTopic(topic)
                .build();

        // Send a message to the devices subscribed to the provided topic.
        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        // Response is a message ID string.
        System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        // [END send_to_topic]
    }
}
```

here message  is com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage type object but  this is not defining in this class

```
Message message = Message.builder()
```

on message alt+enter pressed it show Notification Style and android.os.Message 
But i neend  com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage to be implemented here i used import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage; but didn't worked 
thanks in advance

Comment: Use the RemoteMessage.Builder class for building message instances to send via send(RemoteMessage)

Comment: Try clean Project and Sync Gradle again

Comment: But it sends string type Remote Message is not string type  this code was written  in firbase  documentation don't know why it don't work

Comment: Check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059108/cannot-resolve-symbol-com-google-firebase-messaging-message